# key word not supported 'data source'

Tags: mysql, vb.net

im having problem in my connection. the error said that key word not supported in the data source and i dont what to do next. thanks in advance!

```
Imports MySql.Data
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Public Class frmMasancayClinicSignupvb
    Dim connection As New MySqlConnection
    Dim myReader As MySqlDataReader
    Dim Adapter As MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim myCommand As MySqlCommand
    Dim Dset As New DataSet
    Dim table As New DataTable
    Dim MyQuery As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Private Sub frmMasancayClinicSignupvb_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        connection = New MySqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Mark\Documents\MASANCAYCLINICLOGIN.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30")
        Try
            If connection.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
                connection.Open()
                MsgBox("connected to database")
            Else
                connection.Close()
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try
        connection.Close()


    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you're passing in the arguments for a SqlConnectionStringBuilder - that's for Microsoft's SqlServer database, not MySql.  (see 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.integratedsecurity(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2 ).

MySqlConnection takes "Data Source" but doesn't take those other parameters.  See :

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/connector-net-examples-mysqlconnection.html#connector-net-examples-mysqlconnection-defctor